# Ubuntu 16.04.2 Installing GTX 1080Ti, nvidia-378 driver login loop

Tags: 16.04, nvidia

I have an Nvidia GTX 1080Ti device in my PC. I installed a fresh Ubuntu Image, and used the PPA to install the driver, using apt-get install nvidia-378. I rebooted. When I try to login I get a login loop. I have looked at several questions similar to this one, but none of the solutions seem to work for me. The device is detected, as I get "Graphics Device" [which supposedly is normal according to one forum post I read] when I use nvidia-smi command when I login through the terminal. I would really like to get the graphics card to work.

Thanks!

Update:
I also Tried to install the graphics driver on 16.04.1, and no luck!!

Update 2: 
It seems CUDA functionality is working, but I'm getting no X.

Update 3: 
According to the NVIDIA website, it seems that there is a fix in the latest Update 381.09. I will try the solution in an hour or so, and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working for me was that I needed to disable the internal display driver from the bios to get the GFX card(s) working.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas to begin :

1. Check if the HWE kernel and xorg are installed : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack
2. Install another driver version instead and see what happens

Comment: I'll take a look next week, when I have access to my Computer again. Thanks!

Comment: BTW the 381 driver broke my X server too. I'm running 375.66 now.